# Where to get Settings for camera calibration in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, settings, camera-calibration

I am doing an AR-Project for school and after some struggle i was able to build opencv with aruco and detect markers. Now I need to calibrate the camera for Pose Estimation. I am using [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html#gsc.tab=0).
Now there is stated I have to "Read the Setting" from a xml-file. Where do I find this file? Or do I have to make one myself, if yes how?

Also I want to use a standard chess board for the calibration (I have no printer...). Is this possible and do I have to input the size of this board anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the input.xml that you have to create "https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration/in_VID5.xml". In this file you will notice you have to give size of square on line 9.
Additionally you will also have to create VID5.xml whose path you provide in input.xml on line19. It should have your images that you use to calibrate.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <opencv_storage>
    <images>
    images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx1.jpg
    images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx2.jpg
    images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx3.jpg
    images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx4.jpg
     images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx5.jpg
     images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx6.jpg
    images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx7.jpg
    images/CameraCalibration/VID5/xx8.jpg
    </images>
   </opencv_storage>
```

Try using standard chessboard make sure the surface is flat and has no irregularity if the calibration error and re projection error is between 0 to 1 you can use the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters for your project.